# How to fake time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to mock the Date constructor so that whenever I call new Date(), it always return specific time.

I found Sinon.js provide useFakeTimers to mock time. But the following code doesn't work for me.

```
sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date(2011,9,1));

//expect : 'Sat Oct 01 2011 00:00:00' ,

//result : 'Thu Oct 27 2011 10:59:44‘
var d = new Date();
```

Comment: Just overwrite `Date`. `Date = function(){return 'Sat Oct 01 2011 00:00:00'};`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`sinon.useFakeTimers` accepts a timestamp (integer) as parameter, not a Date object.

Try with

```
clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date(2011,9,1).getTime());
new Date(); //=> return the fake Date 'Sat Oct 01 2011 00:00:00'

clock.restore();
new Date(); //=> will return the real time again (now)
```

If you use anything like `setTimeout`, make sure you read the docs because the `useFakeTimers` will disrupt the expected behavior of that code.

Comment: Here is the exact [link](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/621) to the issue.

Comment: why date 1.9.2011 give October month (expected to get  September...)?

Comment: @AdiEp because months in JS starts  from 0 (january) to 11 (december) - for simplicity :D 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#return_value

Answer (score 29):

How about something like this?

```js
var oldDate = Date;
Date = function (fake)
{
   return new oldDate('03/08/1980');
}

var x = new Date();
document.write(x);
```

You'd then, of course, run:

`Date = oldDate;`

When you wanted to restore things to normal behavior.

Comment: This is neat, but should not be used for large and complex test suites. Sinon.js is preferred in that case, specially for handling the "restore" (recover the original Date constructor)

Comment: Don't forget to `Date = oldDate` during your `afterEach`

Comment: @tothemario why is Sinon preferred over this approach?

Comment: @guptron - Probably because he's the author of Sinon.js :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen this does not appear to be the case https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/graphs/contributors

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```
window.Date = new Proxy(Date, {
    construct: function(target, args) {
        if (args.length === 0) {
            return new target(2017, 04, 13, 15, 03, 0);
        }
        return new target(...args);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer works best as long as you just need to fake time in JS for test purposes, unless you need other features of Sinon.js

Comment: actually this doesn't take care of Date.now(), so I've added that and released it on npm as a small util here: https://github.com/capaj/proxy-date

Answer (score 1):

This is what I needed for my project. A bit complex, but as far as I can tell it's all needed. The internal Date() is a strange beast. Also the code below uses underscorejs.

```js
(window || global).Date = (function (orgDate) {
    var fakeDate = function (y, m, d, ho, mi, se, mil) {
        var backendDate;
        if (arguments.length > 3) {
            backendDate = new orgDate(y, m, d, ho || 0, mi || 0, se || 0, mil || 0);
        } else if (arguments.length > 1) {
            backendDate = new orgDate(y, m || 0, d || 0);
        } else if (arguments.length > 0) {
            backendDate = new orgDate(y);
        } else {
            backendDate = new orgDate();
            backendDate.setFullYear(2015);  // <-- Your year here
            backendDate.setMonth(1);        // <-- Your month here
            backendDate.setDate(2);         // <-- Your day here
        }
        if (this) {
            this.backendDate = backendDate;
        }
        return backendDate.toString();
    }
    _.each(("getDate getDay getFullYear getHours getMilliseconds getMinutes " +
            "getMonth getSeconds getTime getTimezoneOffset getUTCDate getUTCDay " +
            "getUTCFullYear getUTCHours getUTCMilliseconds getUTCMinutes " +
            "getUTCMonth getUTCSeconds getYear parse setDate setFullYear setHours " +
            "setMilliseconds setMinutes setMonth setSeconds setTime setUTCDate " +
            "setUTCFullYear setUTCHours setUTCMilliseconds setUTCMinutes " +
            "setUTCMonth setUTCSeconds setYear toDateString toGMTString " +
            "toISOString toJSON toLocaleDateString toLocaleTimeString " +
            "toLocaleString toString toTimeString toUTCString UTC valueOf").split(" "),
        function (fnName) {
            fakeDate.prototype[fnName] = function () {
                return this.backendDate[fnName].apply(this.backendDate, arguments);
            }
        });
    return fakeDate;
})(window.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
var oldDate = Date;
Date = function (fake)
{
    if( ! fake ) return new oldDate('02/26/2017');

    return new oldDate(fake);
}
Date.prototype = oldDate.prototype;
```

Answer (score 0):

sinon.useFakeTimers is using lolex internally. So it supports object as parameter for [lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex#api-reference)

```
sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date(2019,1,1))
```

is equivalent for

```
sinon.useFakeTimers({
now:new Date(2019,1,1)
})
```

My task was to use same begin date on every integration test (as date should be connected with data in files)
So how i'm using it

```
 clock = sinon.useFakeTimers({
  now,
  shouldAdvanceTime: true,
  advanceTimeDelta: 20
});
```

`shouldAdvanceTime` will allows lolex and sinon to not stop timers in my integration tests.
Also take a look on `config.toFake` parameter. It allows to avoid mocking some functions like `setTimeout`. Or just mock only `Date` constructor