# sinon.js test moment() functions.

Tags: datetime, ember.js, coffeescript, momentjs, sinon

I need to test the following 4 functions which involving moment js. I do not know how I can control over the current time now. The functions are written in coffee script. It's ember.js. Could anyone give some help please. Thanks.

```
start: moment().subtract('days', 30).startOf('day').format('LLL')
  end: moment().format('LLL')

  startTime: (->
    Date.parse(@get('start')).getTime()
  ).property('start')

  endTime: (->
    Date.parse(@get('end')).getTime()
  ).property('end')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fake time in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931069/how-to-fake-time-in-javascript)

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11679436/634824), which demonstrates `sinon.useFakeTimers`.

Comment: @MattJohnson consider posting your response as an anwser