# how to fake current date for jquery-ui-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm implementing a custom algorithm to disable dates depending on a set of rules that also depend on what the current day is.
To test that I would need to set the current date to a specific date.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42387611/928666) that just overwrites javascripts Date function.
My problem is that if I do that the calendar doesn't work as expected anymore.
Most of the time all days are just missing, sometimes all are disabled.

```
var oldDate = Date;
Date = function (fake)
{
    if( ! fake ) return new oldDate('02/26/2017');

    return new oldDate(fake);
}
Date.prototype = oldDate.prototype;
```

How can I test the datepicker with a custom current date?
It should be as easy as setting up a jsfiddle (if possible):
[My current Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ge4bne97/)

Comment: What did you mean by _custom current date?_

Comment: Let's say today is the 4th of July 2017. I want the datepicker to behave as if today was say...christmas eve in 2023.

Comment: still not clear. _today was say...christmas eve in 2023_ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this any more clear. You want to make the datepicker "believe" that today was a specific date you can define that is not the actual current date. As the datepicker builds upon javascripts Date function (I think) you want to make that function return a different date than the current date if you do "new Date()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure about what you need to do, I usually change operating system time, anyway, plain an simple:

```js
  
// DEMO mock date js browser
// comment uncoment to play arround, if you need to automate with or without mock date plain an simple:
mockDateTime('2018/02/02'); // with mock
// mockDateTime() // no mock


$('#date1').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
});

function mockDateTime(mockDate){
   // to do: validate mock date
   if (mockDate !== undefined && mockDate.length > 0)
   {
     var __Date = Date;
     Date = undefined;
     Date = function()
     {
          // to do: more deep checks on arguments          
          if (arguments.length > 0)
          {
              return new __Date(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
          }
          return new __Date(mockDate);
     };
     Date.prototype = __Date.prototype;
   }
}
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why my solution doesn't work whilst yours does. But it does! Thanks a lot :)
Unless there is no one that tells us why we shouldn't use this. I'm going to award your answer.

Comment: It's a big difference on how you override vs on how I'm passing parameters when Date() is called afterwards.

Comment: If you can see I'm not checking if is mock date, I check the parameters, if missing then mock the data if not than do the usual date instantiation with arguments

Answer (score 0):

Set this property and try hope this one hep you.

> **gotoCurrent**

Type: `Boolean`

Default: `false`

*When true, the current day link moves to the currently selected date instead of today.*
Code examples:
Initialize the datepicker with the gotoCurrent option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  gotoCurrent: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't change much. The calendar opens with that fake date anyway. And even with this the dates are missing and you can't change months ie.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fool the DatePicker I would do it in logic. That is, If I understand your question correctly. Consider the following design:

1. You have a function, that accepts a date input, and based on that runs your algorithm which calculates invalid dates based on the input date. Be that real of fake date, doesn't matter works anyway, assuming your invalid date calculator algorithm works.
2. Using this algo, you can always have an array of invalid dates based on the real or fake current date.
3. Giving that array to DatePicker, you can define what dates to disable. (In the `beforeShowDay`.)

Works well, does not need DatePicker hack. See example implementation:

```
function calculateInvalidDatesBasedOnInputDate(inputDate) {
    // your algorithm
    // fake result here, to demonstrate how it works.
    return ["2/14/2017","2/19/2017","2/28/2017"];
}

var fakeCurrentDate = new Date("2017/02/02");

$('input').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    defaultDate: fakeCurrentDate,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy', date);
        return [ calculateInvalidDatesBasedOnInputDate(fakeCurrentDate).indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

See Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/ge4bne97/3/).

Comment: Sorry won't work either. `defaultDate` just set's what date should be opened. And I'm adding my own `beforeShowDay` already. The problem is my function is depended on the current date. Ie. if between the current date and the currently evaluated date is another disabled date do something.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )` feature.

> A number of exceptions may be thrown:
>
> - 'Invalid arguments' if either format or value is null
> - 'Missing number at position nn' if format indicated a numeric value that is not then found
> - 'Unknown name at position nn' if format indicated day or month name that is not then found
> - 'Unexpected literal at position nn' if format indicated a literal value that is not then found
> - 'Invalid date' if the date is invalid, such as '31/02/2007'

This is a way to check that you have a valid date and can return a date object built off the date value you've supplied. You can then use this in your script.

A faster way is simply to set your computer (or a test VM) Date & Time to a date and time in the future or past. This will be past to the browser and then functions like `now()` or `date()` will give you much different results.